# Adding my CV generated by pagedown to my Blog generated by Blockdown

Tags: blogdown, pagedown

I am new to world of webpage generation. Just created new blogging site using "Made with Hugo. Themed by Cupper. Deployed to Netlify. "  .

When I use Addins New Post ( Gui ) it adds into Blogs section and everything is fine . Now I want to add MENU item my CV and add my CV generated by Pagedown Output: html_resume  and Knit : chrome_print .

I am not sure how to add it to my web site page, any one please help me with little bit step by step . I have updated my config.yaml
menu:
nav:
-name:  CV
url:  /CV/
weight: 5

I have my my_resume.Rmd file ready , where should I store? when I KNIT it I got my .HMTL file where should that stay?

And which program I need to update to to call the newly generated my_resume.html